# Select a value from others

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table wich contains:

```
RO;DE;ES;AU;IT;
```

How display data where DE is show on table! I need for milions queries!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  Have you given any thought to normalizing that data?

Comment: i try with function IN but is show if DE is single in table

Comment: @user3027770 And why did you choose to try `IN()` in the WHERE clause.  Have you read documentation on that function to understand why it isn't working for you?

Comment: it working but when in table is DE single not RO;DE;ES;AU;IT;

Comment: Oh god.. do you have cases where you have multiple values in a single "cell" ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have multiple values in the same "cell". You will need to process the string. One way is to use wildcards:

```
SELECT something FROM something WHERE field LIKE '%DE%'
```

Please note however that your table design is absolutely **terrible**. It violates the [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). You should **never** have multiple values in a single cell that you then have to split using wildcards or other string functions. This adds overhead to your queries and will slow them down significantly. You say that you have millions of records, the impact of not having separate values has the potential to be quite large.

You should definitely think of breaking those strings into multiple records if you can.

Comment: It's a good method for milions queries?

Comment: Please see my edit. It answers your question.

Comment: I not have milions records, i have milions calls

Comment: What does that mean ?

Comment: i have milions run queries, in a table is only RO;DE;ES;AU;IT;

Comment: I still don't get it. Post more details in your original question. Post screenshots if possible.